# Why has the file group for the partition grown in size after the alter?

Tags: sql-server, partitioning

A table is partitioned by month/year.  They would like to add 1/1/2024 but what the scheme is the correct sequence until the end where it ends like:

```
[FG_11_2023], [FG_12_2023], {PRIMARY], [FG_01_2024])
```

The partition function ended with:

```
 '2023-12-01T00:00:00:000'
```

The new file group for 1/24 was not getting any data from the file size and after reviewing the scheme, I assumed the data was going into PRIMARY.

I attempted to fix this by altering the scheme with:

```
ALTER PARTITION SCHEME [my scheme name]
   NEXT USED [FG_01_2024];
```

Then I altered the function with split.

```
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION [name of my partition]() 
   SPLIT RANGE ('2024-01-01T00:00:00:000');
```

Why has the file group for 1/24 grown in size after the alter?

[image]

Comment: What about the results is confusing to you? Include that question in your question.

Comment: [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284) [More.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Answer (score 0):

Seems the problem is that the FH_12_2023 actually contains November data, meaning the December data of 2023 doesn't have a FG_13_2023 to go to so it went to PRIMARY. Now that you defined January 2024 to FG_01_2024 it is going where you expect...

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to make it simple meta data fix, you could try parition switching to fix this.

1. First, you need to create a new table using a partition boundary of `2023-12-01` (`FG-01-2024`), for which a new partition function and scheme must be created.
2. Next, switch partition number `37` to the new table. This is purely a metadata operation and does not involve any actual data movement.
3. Afterwards, merge partitions number `37` and `38` on the existing table. This operation combines the two partitions into a single one. Since you have switched out `37`, this merge also doesn't involve data movement.
4. Then, split the `merged partition` using the boundary of `2023-12-01` and assign it to a new filegroup `FG-01-2024`, instead of using the `PRIMARY` filegroup. Since the merged parition doesn't have any data in that boundary you will have no/little data movement here. And, you should have an empty parition created with `FG-01-2024`.
5. Finally, switch the partition that was originally switched out in step 1 and switch it back into the new partition (empty) that you created in step 4.

Also, be sure to note that the steps from 2 to 5 need to be run using `serializable isolation` to block active changes that would otherwise block above process.

Same needs to be repeated to fix boundary `2024-01-01`, with `FG-02-2024`. I would suggest to run this on test environment before prod.

Ref: [More about partition switching](https://www.cathrinewilhelmsen.net/table-partitioning-in-sql-server-partition-switching/)

With above mentioned approach on a staged table,

Before:
[image]

When partition is switched out to staging table for the fix:
(An index rebuild is needed here to migrate the data from `PRIMARY` FG to required FG `FG_01_2024`. But that would be only on that parition/chunk of data.)
[image]

After:
[image]

How? https://gist.github.com/dvsrk/8b6177bea096550d3b609cadea0309c5

Note: There are many things I have assumed with respect to table definition, no PKs, no FKs, no NCIs etc. Depending on your current table's definition the execution steps would change.

Comment: Thank you for the instructions, it is very much appreciated.

Comment: @Marcel added more details to my post, included script I have used to re-produce.